# Can I retrieve the parameters used by a google search anymore?

Tags: parameters, http-referer, referer

In the past I could look at HTTP_REFERER and get the search parameters that were used when the referer was Google.  It seems like this isn't true anymore; is there another way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that the answer to this question is no.  For some reason, Google changed it.